# New to circuits: Creating a toggle button in Logisim using Latch

Tags: switches, circuit-design, latch, logisim

I have just started doing logic and circuits and I am trying to make a toggle button using a button and a latch. I can't seem to figure out how to make the light toggle instead of turning on when the button is realeased[image]

This is what I have, just a basic latch, I just need a direction to go to make it toggle (If the button is pressed the light will only stay off if I keep the button clicked).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NAND gates with one input are useless, they only change the state of input signals.

Toggle flip flops are constructed like this picture from electronicshub.org  [image]

This [link](https://www.electronicshub.org/t-flip-flop/) is going to be usefull for designing a T flip flop.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

just add a T Flip-Flop,you can stay 0 or 1